# Python Async background task to poll cloud queue and yield control while no messages

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Application needs to continuously poll 2 AWS SQS queues for incoming messages and handle them as they come in, but this needs to be done in the background, yielding control when (a)waiting for messages. Also needs ability to gracefully disconnect, hence the `connect`/`disconnect` methods below.

**Using Python 3.8.2**

```py
import asyncio


class App():

    def connect(self):
        print('connecting')
        self.t1 = asyncio.create_task(self.poll_queues_1())
        self.t2 = asyncio.create_task(self.poll_queues_2())
        print('connection complete')

    def disconnect(self):
        print('disconnecting')
        self.t1.cancel()
        self.t2.cancel()
        print('disconnection complete')

    async def poll_queues_1(self):
        while True:
            # simulate an async method that polls a remote cloud Queue for incoming messages
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            print('func 1 polling')

    async def poll_queues_2(self):
        while True:
            # simulate an async method that polls a remote cloud Queue for incoming messages
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            print('func 2 polling')
```

1. This used to work just as is, without ever touching the event loop - I guess there was somehow always one running in the background. Now, I changed computers and somehow it doesn't work on my new computer - I get this:

```
In [2]: app = App()

In [3]: app.connect()
connecting
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f4a7413208aa> in <module>
----> 1 app.connect()

<ipython-input-1-2b38a506601f> in connect(self)
      6     def connect(self):
      7         print('connecting')
----> 8         self.t1 = asyncio.create_task(self.poll_queues_1())
      9         self.t2 = asyncio.create_task(self.poll_queues_2())
     10         print('connection complete')

~\Miniconda3\envs\quant-trading\lib\asyncio\tasks.py in create_task(coro, name)
    379     Return a Task object.
    380     """
--> 381     loop = events.get_running_loop()
    382     task = loop.create_task(coro)
    383     _set_task_name(task, name)

RuntimeError: no running event loop
```

2. Problem is, if I do wrap it all up into an `asyncio.run()`, I never get control back.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the difference in behavior between the two computers.  It doesn't make any sense.  But I can address your item #2.  Asyncio programming requires a different approach.

I can give only a suggested outline of how your application might be structured.

Take all of the things that you would like your program to do, besides the connect stuff that you describe in your question.  Put all that functionality in a coroutine:

```
async def all_the_other_stuff():
     # your code here
```

Now you create a main function something like this:

```
async def main():
     app = App()
     app.connect()
     await all_the_other_stuff()
     app.disconnect()
```

As the last line in the script (typically):

```
asyncio.run(main())
```

One important caveat: in order for this to work, the function all_the_other_stuff must contain one or more await(s).  Unlike threading, with asyncio the concurrency is *cooperative*.  Once a task gets control it will remain in control until the next await, at which point it will yield and other tasks get a chance to run.  With only one thread and only one process, this is how it must be; if you want preemptive (as opposed to cooperative) concurrency you must use threads or processes.